# What's wrong with my app.config configuration for ODP.Net and REF_CURSORS?

Tags: .net, oracle, entity-framework, odp.net, sys-refcursor

I've been struggling for a while with this, im following [this guide](http://download.oracle.com/oll/obe/EntityFrameworkOBE/EntityFrameworkOBE.htm#t3):

This are the steps I have taken so far:

1. Create new console project
2. Add new EntityModel
3. Import "Test" Stored Procedure into Entity Model, sp looks like this:

   ```
   CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SCHEMA.TEST(P_SALIDA OUT NUMBER,
                               P_CURSOR1 OUT sys_refcursor,
                               P_CURSOR2 OUT sys_refcursor) IS
   BEGIN
      P_SALIDA := 15;
      OPEN P_CURSOR1 FOR
      SELECT 125.72 "DECIMAL", 150 "INTEGER", 'JUST PASSING BY' "TEXT" FROM DUAL;

      OPEN P_CURSOR2 FOR
      SELECT 'JUST SOME TEXT' "TEXT" FROM DUAL;

   END TEST;
   /
   ```
4. Add this to app.config:

```
<add name="SCHEMA.TEST.RefCursor.P_CURSOR1" value="implicitRefCursor bindinfo='mode=Output'" />  
<add name="SCHEMA.TEST.RefCursorMetaData.P_CURSOR1.Column.0" value="implicitRefCursor metadata='ColumnName=DECIMAL;NATIVEDATATYPE=Number;ProviderType=Decimal'" />  
<add name="SCHEMA.TEST.RefCursorMetaData.P_CURSOR1.Column.1" value="implicitRefCursor metadata='ColumnName=INTEGER;NATIVEDATATYPE=Number;ProviderType=Int32'" />  
<add name="SCHEMA.TEST.RefCursorMetaData.P_CURSOR1.Column.2" value="implicitRefCursor metadata='ColumnName=TEXT;NATIVEDATATYPE=Varchar2;ProviderType=Varchar2'" />
```

```
<add name="SCHEMA.TEST.RefCursor.P_CURSOR2" value="implicitRefCursor bindinfo='mode=Output'" />
<add name="SCHEMA.TEST.RefCursorMetaData.P_CURSOR2.Column.0" value="implicitRefCursor metadata='ColumnName=TEXT;NATIVEDATATYPE=Varchar2;ProviderType=Varchar2'" />
```

Then I try to import function from the Entity Model I created before but when I click obtain column information after selecting complex type nothing happens, it doesn't show the cursor like the **obe** tutorial.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

EDIT:

So I tried again today, and it's behaving differently this time. Now when I click the Obtain Column Information button in the import function dialog, the dialog just closes and nothing else happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this may sound embarrassing, but it was actually a problem with Visual Studio, I closed the IDE and opened it again, and it started working.

Still I don't recommend this method to anyone, its too much work just to import a function.